# Add warning for code surrounded by '''

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting, quality-filter

I have seen so many people confuse ```` ``` ```` with `'''`, resulting in a post that needs to be edited. Can the linter add a warning that `'''` does not highlight code, or can it be added in the sidebar?

Comment: It occurs to me that using the tilde (~~~) instead of the backtic in the sidebar might be advantageous here. Although... That might be harder to read; the tildes kinda run together a bit. BTW: about 36 posts made this mistake in the past 2 days.

Comment: Side note: Python multiline (*triple-quote*) string literals use `'''` or `"""` as delimiters, and multiline strings are [commonly placed at the top of a module, class or function as documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-docstring). Don’t confuse that use for a misspelling of code fencing.

Comment: @Shog9: how many of those cases were Python questions?

Comment: @MartijnPieters that might make it hard for a linter but to a human it's often evident when there is a docstring or code fencing. Part of the distinction is that code doesn't appear in docstrings

Comment: @alec_a: code can [easily appear in docstrings.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html).

Comment: My mistake. It’s still easily apparent to humans though.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Presumably, any properly used python multiline string literals would be located inside a code block already, right? So we could only gave a warning if the `'''` was outside a code block.

Comment: @divibisan: no, not if the OP didn't format their code properly. My point is that in such cases you can't automatically distinguish between mistaking `'''` for a code-fence and the legitimate Python syntax.

Comment: @MartijnPieters True, but in that case there is still a problem with the code fencing, so a gentle warning about improperly formatted code block would still be appropriate

Comment: Seeing SO already uses tags for language highlighting already. exceptions like Python could be handled differently by either not showing the warning. Or adding a bit of text saying it may not be the case for python users

Comment: Unpopular opinion: If the question is older than a few minutes, downvote and move on. This mistake should be very noticeable to the OP after posting and easy enough to fix.

Comment: I wonder why OP didn't correct the error in the review step. (Probablybecause the source is put at the first and the OP thought they should review that!?)

Comment: > python has left the chat

Comment: @user202729 does anyone actually use guided mode?

Comment: Currently they're the default for users with less than 111 rep.

Comment: Interesting, I thought it’s default until you turn it off for the first time